# Encrypt and Authenticate localhost-traffic?

Tags: encryption, tls, network, tcp

I have some app-components on the same machine but in different languages which need to communicate. I am using socket communication over localhost to do so. The data transferred is confidential.

Should this communication be encrypted?

I mean an attacker would have to be able to run code on the machine in order to intercept this and in that case the user lost anyway, right?

Comment: Have a look at spiped http://www.tarsnap.com/spiped.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need *encryption* to deter passive attackers (evil people who spy on the line and try to work out the data contents), and *integrity* (and its sibling *authentication*) to block active attackers who alter the data while in transit. SSL provides both. However, this makes sense only in contexts where attackers can actually spy on or alter data in transit. For two process on the same machine, communicating through the "localhost" network, attackers who can do that have, usually, "already won".

Details may differ depending on the OS. However, your security will normally depend on the OS, not on encryption. Consider, for instance, a Unix system with multiple users. If your two processes talk to each other, then processes from other users cannot peek into the data exchanges (unless the attacker is `root`, and then he can do anything); however, they may try *impersonation*: at some point, one of your components must connect to the other, and the rendez-vous point for TCP sockets is a port number. An attacker who can run his own code (as an ordinary user) on the machine may maintain a fake server which will receive the connection request in lieu of the intended component. To protect against that, the client would have to make sure that it talks to the expected server (and vice versa): this *can* be done with SSL, but better solutions exist (in this case, using Unix-domain sockets with a path protected by system access rights and/or `getpeereid()`).

If, in your case, the local machine is assumed to be "clean" (no hostile code runs on the machine, under any identity), then connections to localhost are safe and there is no need for any extra protection. If potentially hostile but unprivileged code may run on the machine (that's the "shared multi-user machine" model, as was typical of Unix systems in the late 1980s), then you should use the OS features to make sure that connections are indeed conveyed to the right process (i.e. to a process running on the expected identity). SSL would be overkill.

Comment: Also using a name in a directory (with a owner) for a rendez-vous is much saner than a meaningless arbitrary number that might clash with another choice of arbitrary number.

Answer (score 1):

Well,if the two programs are running on the localhost why do you want to use Network communication? You can use any IPC(interprocess communication) like *Named Pipes* 
You can specify a security descriptor for a named pipe when you call the CreateNamedPipe function. The security descriptor controls access to both client and server ends of the named pipe.

Read the access control Model to learn how to secure named pipes.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374876(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Or you may simply use a Symmetric Encryption Algorithm for which the secret is know to both processes,you may hardcode the secret into the code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, the potential threat is from a malicious process (running locally) getting in middle of two components of the same app running locally and interacting with each other via IPC. Indeed it is a overlooked threat model, and deceiving local attackers like [Man-in-the-Machine (MitMa)](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity18/sec18-bui.pdf) are a real threat even in security critical software such as password manager. Password managers has desktop app as one component and the browser extension as the other, running as a local server and client. I assume the OP's architecture reflects something similar.

The OP did not mention the underlying operating system. The choice of IPC is dependent on the underlying OS, its support to security features or a specific IPC method. Hence, besides network sockets (used for local communication) there is no *one IPC fits all* concept.

In my opinion, IPC should be treated with same prudence as that of a network communication. Hence, if network sockets are to be used, it is tempting to use TLS/SSL based approach, like they do in real network communication, to secure the IPC communication might be tempting. However, remember the following:

> As @Tom Leek pointed out, using TLS/SSL based approach is not worth it. Though they provide security for your IPC components, the necessary infrastructure, including  certification  authorities,  may  be  an overkill. **The goal here is just the authorization of the two ends of IP channel (two processes or components of same software) rather than binding them to strong identities**.

For other OS and IPC methods, here are few things to consider:

- If the software architecture allows to establish IPC channel between two related processes (w..g parent-child), it is good to utilize **anonymous pipes** and **socket pairs**. Since the endpoints of the IPC channel in these cases are created at the same time by the same process, an untrusted process cannot get in the middle.
- MacOS has unique IPC methods that are not available on other OS such
  as [**CFMessagePort**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfmessageport-rs2), where the IPC channels are associated with individual
  login sessions: So, if your worry is from an evil process having another login origin, it is already been taken care here as the process from one login session cannot interact with another.
- **Named pipes** are a reasonable option as @techno mentioned, provided your app is windows specific. However, there are a few things to consider:

  - The named pipes are placed in the root directory of the named pipe filesystem and mounted under the special path\.\pipe\, to which every user (including guests) of the system has access. Suppose your software uses named pipe and it has a specific name. When no pipe with that name exists, any local process can create it for impersonating one end of the IPC. Security descriptors are hence a must.
  - The  creator  of  the  first  instance  decides  the  maximum number of instances as well as specifies the security descriptor,  which includes an access control list (DACL) that controls access to all the instances of the named pipe. remember not to rely on the default descriptor, which grants read access to everyone.
  - Make use of the `FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE` and `FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE` flags. The former ensures that if an instance of the named pipe with the same name already exists, only processes with the `FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE` access to the pipe object can create a new instance. The latter, on the other hand, ensure that it is creating the first instance.